# CKEditor and secure AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor, xss, bbcode

How can I secure my project from XSS using CKEditor? There is not good PHP BBCode Parser (at least I can't find one), so what should I do to validate the incoming string from CKEditor to prevent XSS? Or is out there a GOOD PHP Parser for BBCode that parses evereything from the CKEditor's BBCode?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), so you could even avoid bbcode.

Comment: This looks really good. I just want to ask you which files do I need? Are just the files in the library folder?